# How to add search box in welcome mesaage bar in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento

I am working on Magento 1.9 . I need to display search box in welcome message bar. It can be managed by hacking CSS but that is not proper way.

Can anybody help me with this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the below answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Display hide the search box or remove that by `xml` and go to `app\design\frontend\yourtheme\default\template\page\html` open `header.phtml` and place the below code where you want to show that. now play with css to fix style.

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

for example

```
<div class="header-language-background">
    <div class="header-language-container">
        <div class="store-language-container">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        </div>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?>

        <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('accountLinks') ?></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?> 
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: urfusion: sorry for not replying. I had already tried this. But how we can do it using local.xml?